# "git.osmocom.org: Name or service not known" while cloning osmocom.org repository

Tags: git

I tried to install a GNU Radio module using this comamand:

```
git clone git://git.osmocom.org/rtl-sdr.git
```

but I got this this error:

```
Cloning into 'rtl-sdr'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.osmocom.org:
git.osmocom.org: Name or service not known
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the behavior. Are you sure you are connected to internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you posted, it appears you didn't have an Internet connection when you ran `git clone git://git.osmocom.org/rtl-sdr.git`.

The command is correct, and I've checked that the URL works. Make sure you're connected to the Internet, and try the command again.

Comment: you are right my internet connection was at that time but now sends another error messenge:                  gnuradio@gnuradio:~$ git clone git://git.osmocom.org/rtl-sdr.git
Cloning into 'rtl-sdr'...
error: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none while accessing https://git.osmocom.org/rtl-sdr.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed